# Should I edit a question where most of the content is not related to the actual problem?

Tags: discussion

So I asked a slightly stupid question where, now that I know the solution, it turns out that the title and most of the question are not actually related with the underlying problem. The actual problem is that I misunderstood how "File::Spec->splitdir" works, but that is barely obvious from the question as I though it was to do with something else. Should I heavily edit the question and title to remove all the unrelated details and focus it on the real problem?

[MooseX::Declare how can I return an ArrayRef from an attribute default method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834646/moosexdeclare-how-can-i-return-an-arrayref-from-an-attribute-default-method)

Comment: I would upvote you for editing the question down to the most reusable question.

Comment: In theory, this qualifies as `too localized`.

Comment: @Bobby - sorry, I don't understand what "too localized" means?

Comment: I meant that the question does qualify for the close reason `too localized`.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, I would *not* make major changes to the question simply because an actual answer was given (and accepted) that successfully addressed the actual problem.

In a more general sense, I'm *very much in favor* of stripping questions down to the actual problem as much as possible, as long as sufficient context is in there to both:

1. Allow answerers to know what is going on
2. Allow future searchers the ability to find it by searching on things in the context, since their issue is likely to have a similar context.

The only time(s) when I would be cautious with editing a question substantially is when there have been a number of answers given, especially if they are good answers. In that case, any edits made to the question should be very careful to preserve the full meaning of the original and make sure *not* to completely invalidate answers already given.

If an original question (that has some answers) is *very* far away from the actual problem or has the actual issue buried *very* deeply within it in such a way that pulling it out would be too "damaging" to the original question, I would opt for the "addendum" approach to editing the question. This is more along the lines of adding an additional chunk of stuff to the question, often demarcated in some way (with a line or "EDIT", etc.), that explains the actual or root problem more concisely, along with how you came to realize what the *actual* problem is.